# Plot lines keep disappearing

Tags: plotting

I'm trying to plot the *Compton Shift* which I've defined as:

```
E2[ϕ_] := E1/(1 + (E1/(m*c^2))*(1 - Cos[ϕ Degree]))
```

I've initiated the constants and when I evaluate the function for various degrees, it gives me the correct answer.

The issue I'm getting is that when I try and plot this function (with m = 1, c = 299792458 and E1 = 180), my plot shows a line until the value of ϕ is increased to above ~30-40. I'll get a flat line for small values of Phi but for larger values, the line disappears and I get a blank plot.

What is the reason for this? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What you have is essentially $\frac{180}{1+\mathcal{O}(10^{-16})}$, which is approx $180$. I see a line for large values of phi — http://i.stack.imgur.com/b8loH.png Try plotting `E1 - E2[phi]` if you want to see the change in E2.

Answer (score 1):

This is just to get an answer on record so the question can be removed from not-answered list.

As rm -rf pointed out in a comment to the question, the difference between `E2` and the constant `E1` is extremely small, so a plot of `E2` is essentially a flat line at 180. If the difference between `E2` and `E1` is plotted, something useful is obtained.

```
With[{m = 1, c = 299792458, E1 = 180},
  E2[ϕ_] := E1/(1 + E1 (1 - Cos[ϕ Degree])/(m c^2));
  Plot[E1 - E2[ϕ], {ϕ , 0, 360}, WorkingPrecision -> 20]]
```

[image: plot.png]